# Django: How to iterate over formsets and access cleaned data?

Tags: django, django-forms

What if I want to do something with my formset *other* than immediately saving it?

How can I do this?

```
        for form in vehicles_formset.forms:
            listing.id = None
            listing.vehicle_year = form.cleaned_data['year']
            listing.vehicle_make = form.cleaned_data['make']
            listing.vehicle_model = form.cleaned_data['model']
            listing.vin = form.cleaned_data['vin']
            listing.vehicle_runs = form.cleaned_data['runs']
            listing.vehicle_convertible = form.cleaned_data['convertible']
            listing.vehicle_modified = form.cleaned_data['modified']
            listing.save()
```

(Thus creating multiple listings) Apparently `cleaned_data` does not exist. There's a bunch of stuff in the `data` dict like `form-0-year` but it's pretty useless to me like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you called `vehicles_formset.is_valid()` prior to your snippet above?

Additionally, using a [ModelForm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms) in your formset will allow you to get a listing instance from the form by simply doing `listing = form.save(commit=False)`

Comment: Oh my god.... excellent ninja-debugging sir! I had indeed forgot to call `is_valid()`. Forgot that that added the `cleaned_data` info. The vehicle form is only a subset of the listing model, so I don't think I can use form.save(). Basically there is a bunch of listing data that they all have in common which I want to duplicate, and then just grab the other data from the vehicle forms.

Answer (score 1):

Just to further the previous comment, once `formset.is_valid()` is called, you can also do `save(commit=False)` directly on the formset. This will return a list of the instances, which can then be individually modified and then saved:

```
forms = formset.save(commit=False)
for form in forms:
    form.some_field_name = new_value
    form.save()
```